# Should I require in each module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I don't know how to structure my code or rather I don't know what happens when an app is built with the below structure. I need to use redis, so is it ok to call it in each module or is this a bad practice?

I have 10 functions that I want to have in separate modules to keep my code readable. I am using express js.

So I have an index.js which looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3001;




// the separate modules I want to make
let myFirst = require("./first_function");
let mySecond = require("./second_function");
//etc...


app.use("/my_route1",myFirst);
app.use("/my_route2",mySecond);



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listnening on port ${port}`));
```

The first_function.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const redis = require("redis");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const REDISHOST = process.env.REDISHOST;
const REDISPORT = process.env.REDISPORT;

const redisClient = redis.createClient(REDISPORT, REDISHOST);

const getAsync = promisify(redisClient.get).bind(redisClient);

redisClient.on("error", function(err) {
  return;
  // but since this is an http function should I be calling res.end()?
});


router.all("/", (req,res) =>{

// code for my function 
});

module.exports = router;
```

I will be using redis in quite a few of the modules, so would it just be better to make the index.js file thousands of lines of code or whatever it may come out to be? I don't quite understand what happens when a module is required, if I use 10 modules which all require redis and then require those modules from index.js will I end up with 10 redis clients?

Comment: You can write all redis code in 1 file and export redisClient. Then import redisClient to use wherever you need.

Comment: Does node have any type of header system where I could tell it, that the variables not in scope in this module will be in scope when the code is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const redis = require('redis');

class Connection {

    constructor() {
        this.redisClient = redis.createClient({host : "<hostname>", port : "<port>"});
        let methods = {};
        methods.redisF = false;
        if(this.redisconf.cache) {
            this.redisClient.on('ready',function() {
            methods.redisF = true;
            console.log(" Redis cache is up and running ... ");
            });
        }
        this.redisClient.on('error',function() {
            methods.redisF = false;
        });
    }
    static makeRedisConnection() {
        try {
            return this.redisClient;
        } catch(error) {
            throw "error"
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Connection;
```

Whenever you want to query from redis, take the connection in any of the async function from any other module in the below manner, it will help you write less and more structured code.

```
const redis_conn = Connection.makeRedisConnection();
```

Comment: Is there way to export a reference to one object that handles the connection to the database? I don't want to have to open a new connection per endpoint function invocation. I might be thinking about things the wrong way. Maybe I will just run a separate server instance per function.

Comment: Here we are doing the same thing, the connection is made only once when the project starts and the class loads. And then we are using the "this.redisClient" instance variable which holds the connection. So we are not taking the connection every time. 
Hope that i answered your question.

Comment: I think I am following, I read on the node.js website that they cache calls to require. So, that even if you required a module x amount of times it wouldn't fire the code inside that module... of course this had exceptions.